# Express $\tan3\theta$ as a rational function in terms of $\tan\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, rational-functions

So I know that a rational function is a function that can be defined by a rational fraction and I managed to expand
$$\tan3\theta=\frac{3\tan\theta-\tan^3\theta}{1-3\tan^2\theta}$$
Is this considered as a rational function? Thanks guys.

Comment: $$\dfrac{3t-t^3}{1-3t^2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have represented $\tan3\theta$ as a rational function of $\tan\theta$, because both the numerator and denominator are polynomials *in $\tan\theta$*.